# How will the bug fixes in version 1 reflect in version 2 which has additional features

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, branching-and-merging, svnx

I am not that good with source control,I am having two projects namely with project 1 (version 1) and project 1 (version 2).
Since version 1 is the old one,my only work with version 1 is to fix bugs in it. And i have committed the latest changes to the svn.
Now i have a new requirement starting with version 2,like some additional features. I have not yet committed this project and its just there lying on my desktop.

My main problem is,is there a way that whatever changes or more appropriately bug fixes reflect with project 1(version 1) as well as project 1 (version 2)
But when i am working on project 1(version 2) the changes or new features should not be reflected in project 1(version 1).

Diagram for what i may exactly need.

Project 1(version 1)-----> commit----->Project 1(version 1)committed (bug fixes)
                               ------>Project 1(version 2) committed (bug fixes)

Project 1(version 2)----->commit---->Project 1(Version 2)committed(new features)
Only project 1(version 2) shows committed new features and does not reflect in project 1(version 1)

How do i do this? I am currently using SVNX tool for my mac.

Comment: You can merge files that you have made fixes.

Comment: Not sure if something similar is possible in svn, but I use [Git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for this.

Comment: Aju, make it an answer, and complete it with the underlying repository/branch assumptions it requires?